# Positioning of block partially influences other block

Tags: html, css

I have created a minimal example that represents a simple tabbing system, with tabs on the left and content on the right.

In my example, the bottom position of the tabs influences the positioning of content on the right. This only happens when I `clear` positioning inside the content block.

This is the minimal example's HTML, including a self-explanatory description in the content block. So what goes wrong is that the line below the `clearfix` is wrongly positioned. In fact, it's positioned under the left tabs' bottom.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  width: 20%;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  border-color: blue transparent blue blue;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane.active {
  display: block;
}

.tab-body {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li><a>foo</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a>bar</a></li>
  <li><a>baz</a></li>
  <li><a>boo</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane">
    <div class="tab-body">
      <h1>Foo content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="tab-body">
      <div style="float:right">
        floating right
      </div>
      <h1>Bar content</h1>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <p>
        This line is wrongly positioned to the bottom of the tabs left, why? And how can it can corrected?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know exactly what goes wrong, and therefore how to fix it... To make editing / fixing / trying all a bit easier, here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rde6771s/).

Comment: I want it to be in the flow of the tab's content: just below the heading.

Comment: This example is just there for showing what goes wrong. Of course I can move the clearfix so that it works in this example. However, that does not make it possible to use Bootstrap's grids in the tab's content without suffering that wrong positioning for example. I 'just' want the tab content's to have its own flow that is not affected by the flow of the tabs on the left.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li><a>foo</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a>bar</a></li>
  <li><a>baz</a></li>
  <li><a>boo</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane">
    <div class="tab-body">
      <h1>Foo content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="tab-body">
      <div class="pull-right">
          clearfix
      </div>
     <h1>Bar content</h1>      
      <p>
        This line is wrongly positioned to the bottom of the tabs left, why? And how can it can corrected?
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  width: 20%;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  border-color: blue transparent blue blue;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane.active {
  display: block;
}

.tab-body {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.pull-right{
  float:right;
}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rde6771s/2/)**

Comment: Mmm, maybe my example of applying the `clearfix` for something so elementary as a `pull-right` was not wise... As you might have noticed I'm 
 using Bootstrap, so assume inside the content, I do need `clear`-ing, for example when using a grid in the tab's content.